# Sum columns by multiple criteria in excel

Tags: excel, sum

I'm having trouble finding a short formula when adding columns in excel.

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | Monday | Monday | Tuesday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Thursday |
| **2** | Day | Night | Day | Night | Day | Night | Day | Night |
| **3** | 10 | 5 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 5 | 10 | 10 |

I want to sum only the night of the days whose day number is zero.
You can see the long formula below.

```
=IF(A3=0;B3;0)+IF(C3=0;D3;0)+IF(E3=0;F3;0)+IF(G3=0;H3;0)
```

The result should be 15. Since there are no numbers during the daytime on Tuesdays and Wednesdays, it should be summing night numbers.
It is short for 4 days but very long to write this formula for a month.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `SUMPRODUCT()`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A4:I4=0)*(A3:I3="Day")*(B4:J4))
```

Or `SUMPRODUCT()`.

```
=SUM(FILTER(B4:J4,(A3:I3="Day")*(A4:I4=0)))
```

[image]